# Using Environment Variables across files - GOPATH

Tags: go, environment-variables

This is my first time coding in Go without using GOPATH. 
I have a `go.mod` file. 
I'm attempting to send an email through Sendgrid; I have a file which contains my SENDGRID_API_KEY called `sendgrid.env`.
 
When trying to use the key within my `main.go` file, the value isn't being pulled through.

```
fmt.Println(os.LookupEnv("SENDGRID_API_KEY")) // empty string 
fmt.Println(os.Getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY")) // empty string
```

I've also used 'LookupEnv' which returns false.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And how is the `os` package supposed to know to look for environment variables in your `sendgrid.env` file?

Comment: @icza do i need to set something within that env file, like a package? The API key is exported.

Comment: You need to add the structure of the env file (not the content) so we can tell you how to read it. Like maybe an example of what it looks like

Comment: export SENDGRID_API_KEY=MYAPIKEY

Comment: Go does not magically use or understand "env files". If you want something to read that file, you need to write code (or use a library) to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`os.Getenv()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv) and [`os.LookupEnv()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#LookupEnv) do not check files. If your env vars are in files, you have to load them yourself. Or use a 3rd party lib that does that for you, e.g. [`github.com/joho/godotenv`](https://github.com/joho/godotenv), which would look like this:

```
if err := godotenv.Load("sendgrid.env"); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error loading sendgrid.env file")
}
```

Another option is to export the env vars before launching your app, e.g.:

```
export SENDGRID_API_KEY=mykey
./mygoapp
```

Or in one line:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY=mykey ./mygoapp
```

Or if you have the env vars in a file, you may use the `source` command:

```
source sendgrid.env
./mygoapp
```