# Factory method in golang suffers from cyclic dependency

Tags: go, architecture

I realize questions about cyclic dependencies have been answered before, however, the answers usually simply say to merge packages. So long story short, I have an interface which many types will implement. I want to have a way of choosing which one of these types is to be used during runtime using its name. This would also be used for serialization. I read in the name of the class and then instantiate the correct one.

I have used the strategy pattern. There is a `Base` interface in package `A`.

```golang
package A

import (
    "../C"
)

type Base interface {
   doStuff(p C.Profile) int
}

type Operation struct {
    Base Base
    Data int
}

func (o *Operation) execute(p C.Profile) int {
    return o.Base.doStuff(p)
}
```

Then, there are types that implement that interface in package `B`.

```golang
//file Impl1.go
package B

import (
    "../C"
)

type Impl1 struct {}

func (b *Impl1 ) doStuff(p C.Profile) int {
    ...
}

//file Impl2.go
package B

import (
    "../C"
)

type Impl2 struct {}

func (b *Impl2 ) doStuff(p C.Profile) int {
    ...
}
```

Then in package `C` i have struct `Foo` with a field of type `Base`. This field can point to any of the implementations from package `B`. We can choose the implementation during runtime. This is the struct that I eventually want to serialize.

```golang
package C

import (
    "../A"
    "../B"
) 

type Foo struct {
    bar A.Base
    baz []Profile
    ...
}

func (f *Foo) changeBar(name string, data int) {
    switch name {
    case "Impl1":
        f.bar = Operation{Base: B.Impl1{}, Data: data}
    case "Impl2":
        f.bar = Operation{Base: B.Impl2{}, Data: data}
    ...
}
```

EDIT: Also in the `C` package, we have the `Profile`, which is the reason `A` and `B` packages need to import it.

This code has a cyclic dependency `C` -> `B` -> `C`. An obvious solution would be to move `Profile` to a different package. But this is not possible because `Profile` (and many other similar types in the `C` package) and `Foo` are very tightly coupled and belong in the same package (maybe not so apparent in this minimal working sample). This is what other answers to these type of questions suggest, but I want to learn how to make it work, using good practices i learned from using other languages.

Another solution would be to somehow move the factory method `changeBar` to another package and only use it on the outside of the `C` package (thus avoiding the cycle), passing it results to `C` as parameters, but there are cases (serialization in particular) where I actually need it on the inside of the `C` package.

I have put a lot of time into figuring out this issue but all I end up with is either have everything in one huge package or have every single file in a separate package and have everything be exported. In other programming languages, there is the possibility to either have these cyclic dependencies or import one "class" at a time from a package. What is the way to go in go?

Comment: Why do A & B depend on C? They make no reference to C.

Comment: @Adrian They require the `Profile` type from the `C` package.

Comment: @JamMaster, the dot imports don't help with understanding the problem. Do you mind changing them to normal imports (at least in the question, although I highly recommend you don't use them at all)?

Comment: (another aside, relative import paths aren't supported, so I'm not sure how you're building this as a proper package at all)

Comment: @Peter Ill do that. JimB, I dont know what you mean, I've been using them since the beginning of my Go adventures.

Comment: @JamMaster: I mean that relative import paths are not supported within install-able packages or modules. See https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Relative_import_paths. There is no official documentation ever demonstrating using packages with relative imports.

Comment: You're hitting cyclic dependencies because you need a self-contained shared model package, but you seem to not want to do that because it would "sacrifice the architecture". You must choose whether to protect what you believe to be a superior design, or to create what would actually be an effective design in Go.

Comment: "Factory methods" are code smell in Go.

Comment: @JimB I see! Thank you, thats something important! Peter, I have already tried that, but my problem still remains, I will still need to import the `B` package in `C` and cause a cyclic dependency.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [Registering packages in Go without cyclic dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411316/using-environment-variables-across-files-gopath)

Comment: @Adrian and Flimzy, what I meant with the architecture is basically not wanting answers that are to put everything in the same package. Im still trying to learn trying to learn go and its common patterns, and i think Burak's answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You don't need to put everything in the same package, just the shared model & service interfaces. A good Go architecture will not result in any cyclic dependencies.

Comment: This is an excellent architecture that will not leave you with any cycles: https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1

Comment: @Adrian Thank you, after just skimming through the article, I can see that its a very valuable read!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can break the dependency from C to B using a type registry:

```
package C

import "A"

var TypeRegistry = map[string]func() A.Base {}

func (f *Foo) changeBar(name string, data int) {
   if factory, ok:=TypeRegistry[name]; ok {
       f.bar=Operation{Base:factory(),Data:data}
   }
}
```

Then register your implementations in any package:

```
package B

import "../C"

func init() {
   C.TypeRegistry["myType"]=func() A.Base { return MyType{}}
}
```

Comment: FTR: That's essentially how the [database/sql](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Register) and [image](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#RegisterFormat) packages in the standard library work, among others.